# static files in the media folder not showing when i upload on live server

Tags: python, django, heroku

Hey guys sorry to bother you, I'm new to django and I made a personal portfolio and locally everything is perfect but the deployed one is not loading the images that I upload on the live app.

I tried to see youtube videos a lot of topics over here and I cant find a solution...:(

Heres my code:

**settings.py**

```
import os
import django_heroku
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['***********']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portfolio',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_portfolio.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_portfolio.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_TMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
os.makedirs(STATIC_TMP, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(STATIC_ROOT, exist_ok=True)
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from portfolio import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio/images')
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "portfolio/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row justify-content-center my-3">
  <div class="col-5">
    <img src="{% static 'portfolio/pic_me.jpg' %}" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
  <div class="col-md-9 text-center">
    <h1 id="hometext" class="font-weight-bold">Hello</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<h2 class="mt-5">Portfolio</h2>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  {% for project in projects %}
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">

    {% if project.url %}
    <a href="{{ project.url }}">
      <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2">
    </a>
    {% else %}

    <img src="{{ project.image.url }}" class="img-fluid mb-2">
    {% endif %}
    <div class="textport">
      <h3>{{ project.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ project.description }}</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving media and static files by django in live server and prod is discouraged from the developer themselves, it only should be used when in debug mode.

As for your bug, did you try accessing `/media/portfolio/images/uploaded_image` and see if it shows an uploaded image ?

Also verify the path of your static folder `my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg`

The doc may help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: Hi, in the /media/portfolio/images/uploaded_image the image is there when I upload it, in the static folder does not appear. I will keep trying thanks for the tips

Comment: You can use whitenoise middleware to serve static files in production, very easy. Here is a good explanation of serving static files in production: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment If you are adding or changing files during production I reccomend using a cloud storage bucket.

Comment: Also note that static and media are two separate folders. Your images are uploaded to media, not to static